# How to get scopes info from a GitHub OAuth access token to perform incremental authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, github-api, github-oauth

When performing authorization with the GitHub OAuth API, users are redirected back to a certain application with a temporary code parameter

The temporary code parameter can be exchanged for a access token, sending a POST request to `https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token` as mentioned in the [API reference](https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token)

The response for that endpoint, contains the access token as well as the `scopes` in it, with that said, consider the following flow:

- User authorizes GitHub OAuth with basis scopes
- GitHub OAuth returns temporary code
- Temporary code is retrieved for an access token
- (Incremental authorization case) The User wants to access a feature from my product that requires repository scopes, then the application will need to signal to the user that authorization needs to be performed again with the previously granted scopes and the additional ones

Based on the last step, in order to signal to the user that authorization is required again, would be required to perform a diff between the scopes that were already granted and contained in the access token + the ones that are needed now

Are there other API routes that could be accessed to get more info regarding the access token for that user? As another reference, the OAuth spec refers to that as "Token Introspection Endpoint": https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7662

Answer (score 0):

In GitHub's OAuth API, there is no built-in Token Introspection Endpoint as specified in [RFC 7662](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7662) to directly fetch details about an access token.

However, you can gather some information by hitting the [https://api.github.com/user](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-the-authenticated-user) endpoint. When you make this API call with the access token in the `Authorization` header, the response will include an [`X-OAuth-Scopes` header](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#about-the-response-code-and-headers). This header contains a comma-separated list of scopes that the token has been granted.To find the difference between granted scopes and required scopes for your application, you'll have to do a manual comparison (diff) between the two sets.